# Passing an object to a ViewController from AppDelegate

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, sqlite.swift

In my application, a `Connection` object is initialized in my `AppDelegate.swift`, `applicationDidBecomeActive()`.

How do I pass that `Connection` object to my `ViewController` subclass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In `AppDelegate` create a property

  ```
  private weak var viewController : ViewController?
  ```
- In the view controller in `viewDidLoad` assign `self` to that property

  ```
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
  appDelegate.viewController = self
  ```

Now you can access the view controller from AppDelegate

Comment: What would be wrong with just accessing the connection from the ViewController, a la `let app_delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate` and then `let connection = app_delegate.connection`

Comment: Of course you can do that, too. But you asked to pass the object from AppDelegate to the controller. And consider that the view controller could be instantiated sooner than `applicationDidBecomeActive()` is called.

Comment: I think I will probably do it the opposite way. But this was helpful in letting me know that I can access the AppDelegate singleton from UIApplication.

Answer (score 0):

Instances like `Connection` are usually required throughout the application so the better idea is to create a shared instance of the required object and use anywhere we need.

```
class Connection{
  static let sharedConnection = Connection()
  ....
}
```

usage:

```
let connection = Connection.sharedConnection
```